# How to center text inside an Ubuntu scope card?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes, layout

I originally posted this in StackOverflow, but got no response, so I'm now asking here.

I'm creating a scope for Ubuntu touch and I'm having trouble figuring out how to style the text inside a card the way I want. How do I center the summary component vertically and horizontally inside the card? Here is the layout template in question:

```
R"({
    "schema-version": 1,
    "template": {
        "category-layout": "grid",
        "card-background": "file:///home/user/Pictures/RoundedRect.png",
        "card-layout": "vertical",
        "card-size": "small"
    },
    "components": {
        "summary": "description"
    }
})";
```

Thank you in advance.